# IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 2

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, indexing

I am trying to map key:value pairs from a dictionary onto a matrix and keep getting the error "IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 2"

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np 

cost = {(1, 1, 3) : 0.2,
        (1, 2, 2) : 0.12,
        (2, 2, 1) : 0.15, 
        (2, 1, 3) : 0.7,
        (1, 2, 1) : 0.45,
        (2, 2, 2) : 0.61,
        (3, 2, 2) : 0.5, 
        (3, 1, 3) : 0.19,
        (3, 2, 1) : 0.59}


A = np.zeros((i, j, k))     ## create a matrix of zeros with dimensions ijk
for key in cost.keys():
    A[[key[0] -1], [key[1] - 1], [key[2] -1]] = proc_times[key]        ## Fill the matrix with costs
```

The idea is to map the value corresponding to each (i, j, k) key in the cost dictionary to the (i, j, k) position in the 3D matrix A.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `A = np.zeros((i, j, k))` Here `np.zeroes()` take arguments as int for the dimension. What are the values for `i,j,k` here?

Comment: for this example I am using (3, 3, 2) for the dimensions of A

Comment: You have to make it (3,3,3) as this is a 3*3*3 Matrix. Simply when the `A[[key[0] -1], [key[1] - 1], [key[2] -1]]` is trying to interpret that time it is getting a value out of index. as your last element of nested list that is `[key[2]-1]` is not getting.the index in A